# handle callback function in node js in array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making a simple API which have list of comment and want to push all comment into comments array of object.I am stuck in a problem since few days.It gives the comments on log inside callback function but not outside the callback function.How to solve the issue,thanks in advance.
The code:

```
router.get("/scomment", (req, res) => {
  const commentId = req.body.commentId;
  const postId = req.body.postId;
  let comments=[];
 commentModel.findOne({ postId: postId, commentId: commentId }, (err, doc) => {
    doc.comments.map((comment) => {
    getUsers(comment.email).then((users) => {
        comments.push({
          users,
          comment:comment.commentText
        })
        console.log(comments)
      });
      
    });
    res.json(comments);
  });
  
});
const getUsers = (email) => {
  let user = [];
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      userModel.findOne({ email: email }, (err, info) => {
        resolve({
            "name": info.name,
            "email": info.email,
            "profile": info.profile
        });
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait on all the promises and then return the result of each promise as a merged array after they are done.

```
router.get("/scomment", (req, res) => {
  const commentId = req.body.commentId;
  const postId = req.body.postId;

 commentModel.findOne({ postId: postId, commentId: commentId }, (err, doc) => {
    const promises = doc.comments.map((comment) => {
       return getUsers(comment.email).then((user) => {
        return {
             user,
             comment: comment.commentText
         }
      });
    });

    Promise.all(promises).then((...comments) => res.json(comments))

  });
  
});
```

What you did before doesn't work because `res.json(comments);` is called before each of the `getUsers` networks calls return since the latter is asynchronous, your code won't wait for them unless you chain those statements to when the promises are made.